# .NET 4.0 gives Unknown Exception on XP but it working good on Windows 7

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winforms

I've created program which is intensively using C# sockets and unmanaged C++ DLL with few useful functions Like this one.

```
[DllImport(DLLName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    private static extern void calcData(float ask, float bid, float volume, float lastTrade, string symbolName, TQuoteType type, IntPtr str, out int size);
```

I'm using C# multithreading with 8-10 threads and every one is sending data by sockets every 200ms.
Program working fine on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 , but on XP and Windows Server 2003 it **gives Out Of Memory System Exception after 2 days working**. 
I can't understand what is happening because maximum usage of RAM is 17mb. 
Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: is this the 64bit OS?

Comment: didn't you use any GDI+ library inyour project?

Comment: Is the amount of memory (17 mb) managed memory only - does include unmanaged memory, too?

Comment: Program Written in WinForms it have simple grid on it and nothing more. In Task Manager its showing not more than 17mb.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for any unusual memory consumption by other processes on the XP / 2003 machine.

Given that the program runs fine on the other enviroment it might not even be your program that is causing problem but only a symptom.

As an alternative you can try to capture a dump when your program terminates using, and load it with WinDb or Visual studio

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx

```
ProcDump.exe -ma -t PROCESS.EXE
```

Comment: I'm watching on program process using Process Explorer and it showing that my program using 156mb Private Bytes , how it's possible if in task manager it 4mb ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is caused by Heap fragmentation.

If the program runs for days, and you C++ code use malloc/free or new/delete to allocate/release memory from the heap, on Windows XP and 2003, by default, you'll encounter Heap fragmentation problem. Heap fragmentation is a state in which available memory is broken into small, noncontiguous blocks. When a heap is fragmented, memory allocation can fail even when the total available memory in the heap is enough to satisfy a request, because no single block of memory is large enough.

After Windows XP and 2003, MS enables [Low-fragmentation Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which fixes this problem, Applications do not need to enable the LFH for their heaps. On Windows XP and 2003, you can enable it by code. This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366705%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives an example. (you don't need create another heap, you just need get the default heap with API GetProcessHeap.

Answer (score 0):

First determine if you have a memory leak or not, don't use Task Manager for this, use perfmon instead.  The Mem Usage column in Task Manager is only the working set, which is definitely not the complete picture for your app.  So fire up perfmon, switch to report mode, which is easier to look at, and delete the existing counters.  Then add these counters for your process:

```
Process | Working Set
Process | Virtual Bytes
Process | Private Bytes
.NET CLR Memory | # Total reserved Bytes
.NET CLR Memory | # Total committed Bytes
.NET CLR Memory | Large Object Heap size
```

I'm guessing you have a 32-bit app, so your max Virtual Address Space is 2GB.  Run your app, and periodically check the counters.  If the Process | Virtual Bytes gets near 1.9GB then things will fall apart in strange ways.  Fragmentation could also be the issue, but that would only affect native memory and managed objects in the Large Object Heap.  If the LOH gets too high, that could indicate fragmentation in LOH.

If you do see a memory leak, then you can figure if the leak is in managed code or in native code.  Managed leak if the .NET CLR Memory | # Total reserved Bytes gets rather high.  Native leak if .NET CLR Memory | # Total reserved Bytes stays low and .NET CLR Memory | # Total reserved Bytes gets high.  Remember that managed memory is a subset of the process' total virtual address space.

If you think that you're not seeing fragmentation or a memory leak, then there's the possibility that .NET is throwing the Out of Memory exception and its a red herring, something else has gone wrong.  This is uncommon but not *that* uncommon.  At this point you'll need a debugger.